# Yeoman error during angular scaffold

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

After executing this command:

```
yo angular angular-app
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:84
  if (_.isString(componentConfigFile.main)) {
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at findMainFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:84:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:146:17
    at forOwn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:1301:15)
    at Function.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2595:9)
    at detectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:28:5)
    at wiredep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:57:39)
    at Generator._injectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js:326:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:113:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Anyone can help?

Comment: what version of node do you have installed?

Comment: Node 0.10.25 - 
Yo 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what cases that, but after using the following command I was able to run it nicely.

sudo npm cache clean

Ps.: You might need to delete the create files, run the command above, and then try to execute yo angular again.